# Insert into tableA from tableB where condition set case

Tags: mysql, insert, set

> 1st question:

I am trying to insert into tableA fields from tableB where I have a condition and set a case for a columnA but it does not work. Is it possible to do it without UPDATE?

```
insert into tableA
select date, columnA 
from tableB
where tableB.date between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-31'
set columnA = case
              when columnA like ('%aaa%') then 'aaa'
              when columnA like ('%bbb%') then 'bbb'
              when columnA like ('%ccc%') then 'ccc'
              when columnA like ('%ddd%') then 'ddd'
              when columnA like ('%eee%') then 'eee'
              else columnA 
              end
;
```

**wchiquito** replied and it works.

> 2nd question:

Additionally, I would like to see the solution for the 1st question in case I also want to **group by** date and columnA.

I can do that :

```
insert into tableA
select date, case
              when columnA like ('%aaa%') then 'aaa'
              when columnA like ('%bbb%') then 'bbb'
              when columnA like ('%ccc%') then 'ccc'
              when columnA like ('%ddd%') then 'ddd'
              when columnA like ('%eee%') then 'eee'
              else columnA 
              end
from tableB
where tableB.date between '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-31'
group by date, case
              when columnA like ('%aaa%') then 'aaa'
              when columnA like ('%bbb%') then 'bbb'
              when columnA like ('%ccc%') then 'ccc'
              when columnA like ('%ddd%') then 'ddd'
              when columnA like ('%eee%') then 'eee'
              else columnA 
              end
;
```

But I want to see if there is another way too. A better way to avoid double writing the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `column` is a reserved word, see [9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

See, [12.4 Control Flow Functions - CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

```sql
INSERT INTO `tableA`
SELECT `date`, CASE
                WHEN `column` LIKE '%aaa%' THEN 'aaa'
                WHEN `column` LIKE '%bbb%' THEN 'bbb'
                WHEN `column` LIKE '%ccc%' THEN 'ccc'
                WHEN `column` LIKE '%ddd%' THEN 'ddd'
                WHEN `column` LIKE '%eee%' THEN 'eee'
                ELSE `column`
              END
FROM `tableB`
WHERE `tableB`.`date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-04';
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d9bd3/1)</kbd>

Comment: This one works. But what if I want to use a 'group by columnA'? It is not gonna work.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer: Who is `columnA`?. Clearly define what you want to accomplish, then, upgrade the question. Include tables structure, test data and expected result you want to achieve.

Comment: It was an additional question actually. My purpose is to think things I can't do in mySQL so I can learn more.